# Register a decorator in autofac without manually specifying all dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, decorator, autofac

I have a decorator that has some other dependencies that should also be resolved using the container. 
Example:

```
public class FooDecorator : IFoo
{
    public FooDecorator(IFoo inner, IBar bar, IBaz baz)
}
```

I can register this like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>();
builder.RegisterDecorator<IFoo>((c, inner) => 
    new FooDecorator(inner, c.Resolve<IBar>(), c.Resolve<IBaz>()), "key");
```

This is working, however not that nice that I have to manually specify all other dependencies. What I would like to do is:

```
builder.RegisterDecorator<FooDecorator, IFoo>("key");
```

Where the `IFoo` is resolved to the 'inner' `IFoo` and the other dependencies are resolved from the container. Is this possible, or can I register a decorator with a Func that will result in this behaviour?

Comment: In autofac 5.2 this works: builder.RegisterDecorator<FooDecorator, IFoo>("key"); I was trying the solutions here and only realised after that this was improved since this question.

Answer (score 20):

In order to avoid specifying all dependencies manually, you should register the decorator in *Autofac* and resolve it inside the first parameter of the `RegisterDecorator` method.

```
builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
       .Named<IFoo>("original");
builder.RegisterType<FooDecorator>()
       .Named<IFoo>("decorator");
builder.RegisterDecorator<IFoo>((c, inner) => c.ResolveNamed<IFoo>("decorator", TypedParameter.From(inner)), "original")
       .As<IFoo>();
```

Registering the decorator using named registration will avoid any conflicts.

Comment: This is awesome, but what if you don't know (or care) that the specific implementation of `IFoo` is `Foo`? Is it possible to declare something along the lines of "decorate whatever is currently resolving to `IFoo` with `FooDecorator`"? (assuming IFoo was previously registered to provide `IFoo`, but not necessarily as a _named_ service) - PS I think this is what OP was looking for, too

Comment: @CristiDiaconescu there is no easy solution to do this and without specifying a named to the first decorator you will have 2 registrations in the Autofac container. Feel free to ask a new question if you want further detail on how to achieve what you would like.

Comment: and if your decorator type has an extra parameter, you can define it by registering the type. `.Named<IFoo>("decorator").WithParameter(...);`

Answer (score 7):

Based on Ezolotko's answer, I've made an extension.

```
public static void RegisterDecorator<TInterface, TImplementation, TDecorator>
    (this ContainerBuilder builder) 
    where TImplementation : TInterface 
    where TDecorator : TInterface
    {
        var innerImplementationName = $"{typeof(TImplementation).Name} as implementation";
        var decoratorName = $"{typeof(TDecorator).Name} as decorator";

        builder.RegisterType<TImplementation>().Named<TInterface>(innerImplementationName);
        builder.RegisterType<TDecorator>().Named<TInterface>(decoratorName);
        builder.RegisterDecorator<TInterface>((c, inner) => c.ResolveNamed<TInterface>(decoratorName, TypedParameter.From(inner)), innerImplementationName);
    }
}
```

The nerd in me deeply appreciates how neatly we're all decorating each other's answers to this question about decorators.

*edit*

Autofac v4.9 adds a RegisterDecorator feature. Check it out, it's awesome.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Cyril Durand's answer, here is a generic helper method to register a decorator:

```
    private void RegisterDecorator<TInterface, TImplementation, TDecorator>(ContainerBuilder builder) where TImplementation : TInterface where TDecorator : TInterface
    {
        builder.RegisterType<TImplementation>().Named<TInterface>("implementation");
        builder.RegisterType<TDecorator>().Named<TInterface>("decorator");
        builder.RegisterDecorator<TInterface>((c, inner) => c.ResolveNamed<TInterface>("decorator", TypedParameter.From(inner)), "implementation");
    }
```

If more than one nested decorators are required, a similar method with more generic parameters (TDecorator1, TDecorator2 etc) can be introduced.